# How to get relationship between tables in Progress db

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to get relationships of a table in progress db. For example:

```
OrderDetail: Date, Product_Id, Order_Id, Quantity
```

In this case, I want to get `Product_Id` and `Order_Id` columns are Foreign key

Comment: What is our use case? Do you need that at runtime or development time?

Comment: @MikeFechner, I need to get them on runtime. I have a web site to show tables and create a query by choosing table fields. Thats why I have to show foreign keys to my users.

Comment: You'll have to loop through all tables and seek those that have common fields and indexes.

Comment: @MikeFechner,is there any way to get them by query ?

Comment: A sample program with the queries on the _file/_field/_index tables is _treldat.p from https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/2934.ade-openedge-11-7-2-development-tools-source-code

Answer (score 4):

The OpenEdge database does not have explicit support for "foreign keys".

Some application schemas have naming conventions that might help you.

You can, as Mike mentioned, loop through the meta schema tables _file, _field and _index and apply logic that follows a such a naming convention  but there is no generic solution that can be applied to all OpenEdge databases.

For instance, if you naming convention is that a field name of tableNameId indicates a potential foreign key for tableName you might try something like:

```
find _file no-lock where _file._file-name = "tableName" no-error.
if available( _file ) then
  do:

    find _field no-lock where _file-recid = recid ( _file ) and _field-name = "tableNameId" no-error.

    if available( _field ) then
      do:

        message "common field exists!".

        find first _index-field no-lock where _field-recid = recid( _field ) no-error.
        if available( _index-field ) then
          do:

            message "and there is at least one index on tableNameId!".

            find _index no-lock where recid( _index ) = _index-recid no-error.

            message _index-name _unique _num-comp.  /* you probably want a unique single component index */

          end.

      end.

  end.
```

Answer (score 0):

While the OpenEdge database and the ABL engine don't know about relationships or external keys, the SQL engine does implement foreign key constraints. See
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000034195

I don't know if this is useful for you. These constraints would be to be defined first if they don't exist already, which is unlikely if your application is mainly ABL and not SQL. Also the website would need to access the database through SQL. It is not enough to write SQL statements in your ABL code, the access needs to go through the SQL engine.